# Where is javakey now?

Tags: java, security, applet, digital-signature

I've been reading an old Java book where it gives an example on how to sign an applet using javakey. I'm using the openjdk-8 for my development and the command line in Linux and it says command not found: javakey. I know Java has already been acquired by Oracle corporation though I still want to know what happened to javakey, but couldn't find any information on the internet.

Comment: Not sure if it helps, but: applets are dead technology. The only "good reasons" to learn about applets in 2016 would be: to understand why nobody is using them anymore; or maybe, if your company is still using them; and you absolutely **must** know about them.

Comment: See [Java Plugin support deprecated](http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2016/01/rest-in-hell-java-plug-in/) and [Moving to a Plugin-Free Web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/moving_to_a_plugin_free). *"learn about applets in 2016 would be: to understand why nobody is using them anymore;"* @Jägermeister Huh.. had not thought of *that* reason for developing applets. Or, I suppose as *punishment*. It'd have to be a pretty serious crime though.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Thanks for the information, I was actually wondering why Chrome dropped support for NPAPI. Now I know that browser vendors will do so as well in the near future if not sooner.

Comment: @Jägermeister I didn't know that. Thanks for updating me. I just fancied with it anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you're referring to a combination of the [`keytool`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/keytool.html) & [`jarsigner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jarsigner.html).

But ignore anything in the `keytool` documentation about generating your own 'self signed' code signing certificate. Self signed certificates are no longer accepted by the Java plug in.

Comment: Actually I am, I just needed some validation. The problem I had
following the guide from the [Oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/security/rsa_signing.html), was the step on generating a 
certificate using VeriSign/Thawte because I didn't have an account. 
The answer to my problem was from a question also posted here on 
stackoverflow. It turns out I can generate my own using openssl, but 
like you said self-signed certificates are no longer accepted by the 
Java plug in, and so I found out.

Answer (score 2):

`javakey` became `keytool` in 1998, when Java 1.2 was released.

Comment: I thought so. I just needed some validation.